# Only iterating through first list in a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def translateStrand1(dnaStrand):
    protein = []
    proteinList = []
    start = dnaStrand.find('ATG')
    end = len(dnaStrand)
    totalLength = dnaStrand[start:end]

    remove = totalLength.split('TAG')
    for str in remove:
        split_str = [str[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(str), 3)]
        protein.append(split_str)
        print(protein)
        for list in protein:
            for i in list:
                protein = (aminoAcid(i))
                proteinList.append(protein)
            return proteinList
```

Current result:

```
>>> translateStrand1('ABCATGTATGCCTAGATGCTGCGCTAGATGGTTGCA')
[['ATG', 'TAT', 'GCC']]
['Met', 'Tyr', 'Ala']
```

Required result for the given string:

```
>>> translateStrand1('ABCATGTATGCCTAGATGCTGCGCTAGATGGTTGCA')
[['Met, 'Tyr', 'Ala'], ['Met', 'Lev', 'Arg'], ['Met', 'Val', 'Ala']]
```

Looks like only the first list in protein is being iterated over instead of all lists. Also I only need the corresponding abbreviation and not the letters from the string in my output.

Comment: You have a `return` at the bottom of the `for list in protein` loop, at which point the function will exit.

Comment: first thing, don't use keywords as variable: `str`, `list`

Comment: What is the sample input value  for your function `translateStrand1(dnaStrand)`

Comment: what does the method aminoAcid(i) do?  also can u add what value the variable holds at the print statement? from variable protein do u want to iterate only on the first element?

Comment: Make a [mcve].  Provide at least a rudimentary implementation of `aminoAcid`.  Your example should reproduce the issue without additional edits or guessing.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should avoid using the variable names `str` and `list`, because these are special 'keywords' in python. It could cause you problems.

Second, your primary problem is where you are returning your results. You've placed the return function inside of your for loop, and that is why you aren't getting the full list of lists. This should be placed outside of your for loop like so:

```
def translateStrand1(dnaStrand):
    protein = []
    proteinList = []
    start = dnaStrand.find('ATG')
    end = len(dnaStrand)
    totalLength = dnaStrand[start:end]

    remove = totalLength.split('TAG')
    for sequence in remove:
        split_str = [sequence[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(sequence), 3)]
        proteins_in_seq = []
        protein.append(split_str)
        for i in split_str:
            amino_acid = aminoAcid(i)
            proteins_in_seq.append(amino_acid)
        proteinList.append(proteins_in_seq)
    return proteinList
```

Indentation in python is very important, it is used to nest commands.

Lastly, you are getting both the base pairs and amino acid abbreviations because you are using a print statement `print(protein)`. If you don't want this, then you should remove this line.

P.S. You are also using the `protein` variable name for two different purposes. You might want to check that this is really your desired behavior.

Comment: What about the indentation in the outer loop ?(there is 3) it seems he should not contain the other loops inside...

Answer (score 0):

***Note:* The indents must be in place.**

You wrong in last for loop like [John Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/494134/john-gordon) said. And I saw that your sample code is wrong in many places, it was typing mistake? You must to take `return proteinList` out of for loop. This is the right code:

```
def translateStrand1(dnaStrand):
    protein = []
    proteinList = []
    start = dnaStrand.find('ATG')
    end = len(dnaStrand)
    totalLength = dnaStrand[start:end]

    remove = totalLength.split('TAG')
    for str in remove:
        split_str = [str[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(str), 3)]
        protein.append(split_str)
    print(protein)
    for list in protein:
        for i in list:
            protein = (aminoAcid(i))
            proteinList.append(protein)
    return proteinList # this line is fixed
```